# bootstrap 4 forms inline

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How to make this form using standard bootstrap 4.3 tools?
[image]

This is what I could do. But unsuccessfully.

```
                <div class="col-12 mb-3 form-inline">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="trade_number" class="mr-2">Цена начальная</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="От">
                        <div class="mx-2">-</div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="До">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 mb-3 form-inline">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="trade_number" class="mr-2">Цена текущая</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="От">
                        <div class="mx-2">-</div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="До">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

but i get this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by previous post works only for given labels, if the label size increases or decreases it gets misaligned. Also its good practice to use `row` and `col` in order to avoid unexpected results when used randomly. A `form-inline` class will append items one after other in single line so it will have no idea of length and justification of items in next line. So it works better in cases where you have inline forms. A better approach in this case would be grid layout using `row` and `col`. It also gives responsiveness based on device size if that's something that you might want. Please see below code snippet and also a link to codepen for the same.

https://codepen.io/R1112/pen/LYPvXyg

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="row m-3">
  <div class="col-12 m-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3"><label for="trade_number" class="float-left">Цена начальная</label></div>
      <div class="col-4"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="От"></div>
      <div class="col-1">
        <div class="align-middle">-</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="До"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 m-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3"><label for="trade_number" class="float-left">Цена текущая</label></div>
      <div class="col-4"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="От"></div>
      <div class="col-1">
        <div class="text align-middle">-</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="До"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-12 mb-3 form-inline">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="trade_number" class="mr-2 col-mb-4">Цена начальная</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control " placeholder="От">
                        <div class="mx-2">-</div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="До">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 mb-3 form-inline">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="trade_number" class="mr-2">Цена текущая</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="От">
                        <div class="mx-2">-</div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="До">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: it's output same as your output which you have need.